# Moving to Data Center

Tags: windows-server-2008, datacenter

Please, give me any advice.
Our company has decided to move servers to a data center since we are having a major network traffic jam. The data center provides 100MB bandwidth and full 42 unit cabinet for us. Right now, I am planing to have two firewalls for a failover and changing DNS informations for a web server. Is there anything that I have aware of before I move them to the data center?

```
<Servers>
1. Web Server
2. Exchange Server
3. SQL Servers
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what kind of servers you're planning on moving to the data center.

Comment: You seem to be missing a pair of redundant switches to put behind the firewall. Might want to ask them about cabling.

Comment: Can't your current provider just sell you more bandwidth or are they out of bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a global catalog server there as well for exchange. Having all of the GCs on-site and exchange off-site can cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your provider. They should have a checklist for whatever you need; in fact, they should probably have some sort of technical account manager or other person to specifically help you.